# How can I maintain/send login credentials to webview as session variables from activity

Tags: java, android, session, webview

I'm storing user's login and password in my native app. I need to send it to webview url as session variables.

In php file I will be retrieving it as `$_POST['email']`. Even I'm getting response for successfully retrieved from activity.

But the session is lost in other pages.

So how can I maintain or send credentials to webview?

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity {

//private Button button;

private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
SharedPreferences preferences;
public static final String Email = "emailKey";
public static final String Password = "passKey";
public static final String PhoneNum = "phonekey";
String URL = "http://myweb.com/index.php";
int success;
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

@SuppressLint("NewApi") /** Called when the activity is first created. */@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);
    this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.loadUrl(URL);

    new SetSession().execute();

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

   // progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Mainactivity.this, "Please wait a moment we are setting up environment", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(Shop.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager localCookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
      localCookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(this.webview, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }       
    else {
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    Log.i("letzkit360", "At onCreate");
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(1);

}
class SetSession extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait a moment we are setting up environment", "Loading...");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = preferences.getString(PhoneNum, "");
        String password = preferences.getString(Password, "");

        Log.d("email", email);
        Log.d("password",password);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNum", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        JSONObject json =   jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);        
        Log.d("Shop JSON", ""+json);


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         progressBar.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this is not PHP, this is JAVA.

Comment: I've added PHP tag because I'm using server side implementation using PHP. That's why I've added the tag 'PHP'.